# nexenta and hotswap sas disks. cfgadm not working properly

Tags: sas, lsi, nexenta, hotswap

There is a problem with the hot-swap SAS drives.

Initial data:
Nexenta 4.0.2
Server-based Supermicro (MB S5520HC, internal RAID controller RMS2LL080/LSI 2008), 12 HDD SAS 300G 10 HDD SATA 1T, 2 SSD 160G.

Disks are divided into three pools:

- System SAS 2x300 mirror
- "fast" array of SAS drives 10 (9 + 1 spare)
- "slow" SATA array 10 drives

At some point, out of order, two SAS drives:

```
NAME                         STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        sas                          DEGRADED     0     0     0
          raidz1-0                   DEGRADED     0     0     0
            c1t5000C50007DCF821d0    ONLINE       0     0     0
            c1t5000CCA0052FFDD5d0    ONLINE       0     0     0
            c1t5000CCA005349D15d0    ONLINE       0     0     0
            spare-3                  FAULTED      0     0     0
              c1t5000CCA00534D625d0  FAULTED      0     0     0  external device fault
              c1t5000CCA0053658B5d0  ONLINE       0     0     0
            c1t5000CCA00534F2D5d0    ONLINE       0     0     0
            c1t5000CCA00534F33Dd0    ONLINE       0     0     0
            c1t5000CCA00534F471d0    ONLINE       0     0     0
            c1t5000CCA0053571D1d0    ONLINE       0     0     0
            c1t5000CCA00535A3A5d0    ONLINE       0     0     0
        logs
          c0t500151795950C847d0      ONLINE       0     0     0
        spares
          c1t5000CCA0053658B5d0      INUSE     currently in use



  pool: syspool
 state: DEGRADED
status: One or more devices are faulted in response to persistent errors.
        Sufficient replicas exist for the pool to continue functioning in a
        degraded state.
action: Replace the faulted device, or use 'zpool clear' to mark the device
        repaired.
  scan: scrub repaired 0 in 0h3m with 0 errors on Sun Oct  4 03:03:56 2015
config:

        NAME                         STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        syspool                      DEGRADED     0     0     0
          mirror-0                   DEGRADED     0     0     0
            c1t5000C500072BB235d0s0  FAULTED      1    20     0  external device fault
            c1t5000C500072BE655d0s0  ONLINE       0     0     0
```

Next, make a replacement procedure zpool offline / detach and cfgadm -c unconfigure for each disk. After installing one drive (in this case, syspool) in the logs can see the following:

```
Oct  9 18:28:43 nxstor genunix: [ID 408114 kern.info] /pci@0,0/pci8086,3a40@1c/pci8086,350e@0/iport@ff/disk@w5000c50007dcf7ed,0 (sd26) online
Oct  9 18:28:43 nxstor pcplusmp: [ID 805372 kern.info] pcplusmp: pci-ide (pci-ide) instance 0 irq 0x12 vector 0x41 ioapic 0x8 intin 0x12 is bound to cpu 14
Oct  9 18:28:43 nxstor pcplusmp: [ID 805372 kern.info] pcplusmp: pci-ide (pci-ide) instance 1 irq 0x15 vector 0x42 ioapic 0x8 intin 0x15 is bound to cpu 15
Oct  9 18:28:43 nxstor pcplusmp: [ID 805372 kern.info] pcplusmp: pci-ide (pci-ide) instance 0 irq 0x12 vector 0x41 ioapic 0x8 intin 0x12 is bound to cpu 0
Oct  9 18:28:43 nxstor pcplusmp: [ID 805372 kern.info] pcplusmp: pci-ide (pci-ide) instance 1 irq 0x15 vector 0x41 ioapic 0x8 intin 0x15 is bound to cpu 1
Oct  9 18:39:53 nxstor genunix: [ID 888150 kern.warning] WARNING: Device not found in device tree. Skipping device unretire: /pci@0,0/pci8086,3a40@1c/pci8086,350e@0/iport@ff/disk@w5000c500072bb235,0
Oct  9 18:39:53 nxstor genunix: [ID 484473 kern.notice] NOTICE: Not retired: /pci@0,0/pci8086,3a40@1c/pci8086,350e@0/iport@ff/disk@w5000c500072bb235,0
Oct  9 18:39:53 nxstor genunix: [ID 888150 kern.warning] WARNING: Device not found in device tree. Skipping device unretire: /pci@0,0/pci8086,3a40@1c/pci8086,350e@0/iport@ff/disk@w5000cca00534d625,0
```

Disks and disk @ w5000cca00534d625,0 disk @ w5000c500072bb235,0 are two problematic disk, which have been removed from the system.

Installed HDD defined cfgadm:

```
root@nxstor:/volumes# cfgadm -al
Ap_Id                          Type         Receptacle   Occupant     Condition
Slot2                          sas/hp       connected    configured   ok
c1                             scsi-sas     connected    configured   unknown
c1::dsk/c1t5000C50007DCF7EDd0  disk         connected    configured   unknown
<cut>
```

However, this disc format does not see the utility fdisk too:

```
root@nxstor:/volumes# fdisk /dev/rdsk/c1t5000C50007DCF7EDd0
fdisk: Cannot stat device /dev/rdsk/c1t5000C50007DCF7EDd0.
root@nxstor:/volumes# 
root@nxstor:/volumes# ls -la /dev/rdsk/c1t5000C50007DCF7EDd0
/dev/rdsk/c1t5000C50007DCF7EDd0: No such file or directory
```

Moreover, NMS see the following:

```
Trigger Name: nms-fmacheck
           Fault ID: 5
 Error Repeat Count: 5
     Error Severity: CRITICAL
    Error TimeStamp: Tue Oct 13 14:21:54 2015

Description:
FMA Module: ereport.io.scsi.disk.attach-failure

Details:

List of last errors :
Oct 13 13:48:02.6970 ereport.io.scsi.cmd.disk.tran   
<cut>  
Oct 13 14:21:05.7075 ereport.io.scsi.cmd.disk.tran   
Oct 13 14:21:53.6196 ereport.io.scsi.cmd.disk.dev.rqs.derr
Oct 13 14:21:53.6197 ereport.io.scsi.disk.attach-failure

List of last errors :
=========: Event Details :========
SOURCE: ereport.io.scsi.disk.attach-failure
nvlist version: 0
    class = ereport.io.scsi.disk.attach-failure
    ena = 0x58420a3d24100401
    detector = (embedded nvlist)
    nvlist version: 0
        version = 0x0
        scheme = dev
        device-path = /pci@0,0/pci8086,3a40@1c/pci8086,350e@0/iport@ff/disk@w5000c50007dcf7ed,0
        devid = id1,sd@n5000c50007dcf7ef
    (end detector)

    devid = id1,sd@n5000c50007dcf7ef
    __ttl = 0x1
    __tod = 0x561cdb41 0x24f05942

=========
```

If we assume that the new drive is also defective and put others get even more strange picture. The logs installation disk does not appear at all. But the information is displayed on the withdrawal of the disc:

```
Oct 13 14:50:26 nxstor scsi: [ID 107833 kern.notice] /pci@0,0/pci8086,3a40@1c/pci8086,350e@0 (mpt_sas0):
Oct 13 14:50:26 nxstor   PhysDiskNum 2 with DevHandle 0x23 in slot 0 for enclosure with handle 0x0 is now offline
```

Empirically, it has been found that the problem only applies to SAS drives. This in turn has suggested about the problem in the cfgadm with MPxIO driver and mpt_sas (turns out this is a known problem solaris and wrote that she was resolved, but it is not clear whether it is passed in opensolaris).

What to do next? Who ever encountered a similar problem?

Drivers and firmvare SAS controller:
MPTSAS HBA Driver 00.00.00.24
firmware-version 5.40.1.0
SAS drives two species: Hitachi Ultrastar 15K300 HUS153030VLS300 and Seagate Cheetah 15K.5 ST3300655SS.

Comment: Can you tell us if you have the community edition of Nexenta, or are you using a supported version? This looks like a Nexenta quirk that their support may be able to work through.

Comment: We use the community edition. I also asked this question in a forum community.nexenta.com, but there are no answer.